# Google Cloud Storage: Images Wont Copy To Other Buckets

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have create a method that transfers a set amount of images from a called folder through google cloud storage, however when running it creates the directory but does not transfer any images

```py
def Cloud_Transfer(UserLabel, UserCounter):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    gcs_bucket_store = 'export'
    gcs_bucket_upload = 'active'
    counter_limit = UserCounter
    label = UserLabel
    label_prefix = 'verified images/' + label + '/'
    source_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(gcs_bucket_store)
    blobs = source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix = label_prefix)
    counter = 0
    for blob in blobs:
        if counter == counter_limit:
            print("Done")
        else:
            source_blob = source_bucket.blob(blob.name)
            destination_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(gcs_bucket_upload)
            new_blob = source_bucket.copy_blob(source_blob, destination_bucket, blob.name)
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

the images are located in a path "verified images/"label"/image.jpg"
I expect this file to be transferred across however only end up with the path and no image copied

Comment: Could you found any logs on Stackdriver Logging for GCS ?

Comment: at the moment I am running it locally, the only logs I can find are the creation of the buckets but have deployed other versions for testing so there should be other logs as well

Comment: Directories do not exist in Cloud Storage. Check to see if what you think is a directory is actually your object. Specify the prefix without the trailing slash. Add `delimiter='/'` to your `list_blobs()` call.

Answer (score 0):

This links are examples of how to perform basic operations on blobs (objects) in a Google Cloud Storage bucket:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/snippets.py

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets#storage-create-bucket-code_samples